# Lipschitz constant of a function of matrix

Tags: lipschitz-functions

The function is given by
$f(X) = (AX^{-1}A^\top + B)^{-1}$ where $X$, $A$, and $B$ are $n \times n$ positive definite matrices.

I'm trying to find the Lipschitz constant such that $\| f(X)-f(Y) \| \leq L \|X-Y\|$ where $X \geq 0$ and $Y \geq 0$. Motivated by Lemma 3.1 in *Nonlinear Systems* (H. Khalil, 3rd Ed.), I tried to find the derivative of $f(X)$ (i.e. $\| \frac{ \partial f(X)}{\partial X} \|$) but it's not easy to find the derivative of a function of a matrix over a matrix.

How can I find the Lipschitz constant? or please let me know if there exists a way to calculate the derivative of a function of a matrix.

Comment: I posted the same question in mathoverflow (https://mathoverflow.net/questions/334248/lipschitz-constant-of-a-function-of-matrix) but, I think this place is more appropriate for this question. So I ask again here.

Answer (score 0):

Over at [mathoverflow](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/334248/lipschitz-constant-of-a-function-of-matrix/334315#334315) I have provided an argument that $L=\|A^{-1}\|^2$ is a Lipschitz constant for $f(X)$.